# Can you find an exact html tag with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to add an arbitrary attribute to some HTML code files. Let's call it... data-custom.

Let's assume this fragment is the html that BeautifulSoup is going to load.

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
    <label asp-for="Driller.FirstName"></label>
    <input asp-for="Driller.FirstName" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

Now the code:

```
tagId = 'theonetochange'
outerHtml = '<input asp-for="Driller.FirstName" class="form-control" />'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

# Find by ID
tag = soup.find(id = tagId)

# If that didn't work, find the exact HTML code
if tag is None: 
    tag = soup.find(string = outerHtml) # This is what doesn't work

if tag is None:
    print("Target not found")
    exit()

# Add the custom attribute
tag["data-custom"] = "mycustomdata"

# Print out the results
print(str(soup))
```

I want to ultimately come out with this:

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
    <label asp-for="Driller.FirstName"></label>
    <input data-custom="customdata" asp-for="Driller.FirstName" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

Since the html doesn't contain that ID, it should search using the exact HTML code I provided, but it looks like maybe that `soup.find(string = "...")` is only good for the contents of a tag and not the tag itself? Is there a way to select the entire  tag in that way?

Comment: Instead of trying to find the literal element, how about looking for an `input` element with the attribute `asp-for` set to `"Driller.FirstName"` and attribute `class` set to `"form-control"`? I.e. `soup.find('input', {'asp-for': 'Driller.FirstName', 'class': 'form-control'})`

Comment: @Grismar No, if I could just use other attributes I would do so. As I said, the idea here is that I'm not just looking for the specific input I pointed out as the example, but any arbitrary html tag that lacks an ID attribute.

Comment: @Oskar No. The extract() method takes a reference to an element and gives you the outer HTML. I'm trying to do the opposite -- given a chunk of HTML code, I want to get a reference to the matching element.

Comment: Where is the fragment you're looking for coming from - note that the attributes I suggest looking for make up exactly the HTML bit you're looking for. The HTML has to be coming from somewhere and that somewhere is probably where you have access to these values.

Comment: Let's suppose that this is a function and I'm passing in outerHtml as a search term. If you have a suggestion for extracting all the attributes from outerHtml and using them to construct a BS search, that would help.

Comment: What you're suggesting can definitely be done, but it raises the question if the problem you're asking about isn't an XY problem. You say you want to find a specific bit of html code in a larger document, but the problem you're really trying to solve appears to be "I want to add an attribute to elements that meet specific criteria". In your case 'set data-custom to "customdata" on all input elements of class "form-control" that have attribute asp-for as "Driller.FirstName"'. There's actually more efficient ways of doing that with the default bs4 parser lxml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question and the discussion in the comments, it appears you have what is known as a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

This is very common in programming and often results from the common anti-pattern known as [the law of the instrument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument) (often called 'the Golden Hammer'). Once you know how to use a specific tool, you use it to solve every problem because every problem looks like it could be fixed with that tool. That may be true, but a hammer is rarely the best tool to drive in a screw.

Here you are asking how to use beautifulsoup to find a specific fragment of HTML so that you can replace it with a similar fragment. Specifically, you want to find fragments like these:

```
<input asp-for="Driller.FirstName" class="form-control" />
```

And replace them with these:

```
<input data-custom="customdata" asp-for="Driller.FirstName" class="form-control" />
```

A very straightforward way would be blatant string replacement, but you probably already (correctly) identified that this is very sensitive to small changes in formatting of the HTML.

You could perhaps use `bs4` for that, and the approach of replacing HTML text with HTML text seems like it might work, but `bs4`'s default parser `lxml` actually already has everything you need to do it in a simpler and more robust fashion:

```
import bs4
from lxml import etree

# this is just a small example document, you can use etree to load a file as well
document = '''
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label asp-for="Driller.FirstName"></label>
      <input asp-for="Driller.FirstName" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label asp-for="Driller.FirstName"></label>
      <input class="form-control" asp-for="Driller.FirstName" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label asp-for="Driller.FirstName"></label>
      <input class="form-control" />
      <input asp-for="Driller.FirstName" />
      <input class="form-control" asp-for="Driller.OtherName" />
      <input class="not-form-control" asp-for="Driller.FirstName" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
'''

# loading the document, for a file you'd use `etree.parse`
doc = etree.fromstring(document, parser=etree.HTMLParser())

# loop over exactly the elements you want to change, using XPath to select them
for element in doc.xpath('//input[@class="form-control" and @asp-for="Driller.FirstName"]'):
    element.attrib['data-custom'] = 'mycustomdata'

print(etree.tostring(doc).decode())
```

The output:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label asp-for="Driller.FirstName"/>
      <input asp-for="Driller.FirstName" class="form-control" data-custom="mycustomdata"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label asp-for="Driller.FirstName"/>
      <input class="form-control" asp-for="Driller.FirstName" data-custom="mycustomdata"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label asp-for="Driller.FirstName"/>
      <input class="form-control"/>
      <input asp-for="Driller.FirstName"/>
      <input class="form-control" asp-for="Driller.OtherName"/>
      <input class="not-form-control" asp-for="Driller.FirstName"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note that you asked about putting the `data-custom` attribute first. That shouldn't matter since the order of attributes in XML and HTML is supposed to be meaningless, but if you're dealing with some system that requires it to be first, you could do that by replacing the `attrib` assignment:

```
    # keep the old attributes in order, leave out data-custom if it was there
    old_attrib = {k: v for k, v in element.attrib.items() if k != 'data-custom'}
    new_element = etree.Element(element.tag, {'data-custom': 'mycustomdata'} | old_attrib)

    # copy any other parts (input wouldn't have children, but then order shouldn't matter either)
    new_element[:] = element[:]
    new_element.text = element.text
    new_element.tail = element.tail

    # replace the original
    element.getparent().replace(element, new_element)
```

Comment: The placement of the custom attribute was not important, no -- just its presence. I just used a quick and dirty exact-match string replacement for items that didn't have a unique ID since in this case it was just a once-over fix-all-the-things kind of change, but if I needed it to be more robust for long-term usage, this sounds like a good approach.